# modify array value from php file in codeigniter or php

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have php file like below and i want to read this php file and get all array value in this php file and i can update value of array

```
<?php
$lang['country_name']="Country Name";
$lang['zip_code']="Zip Code";
$lang['flag']="Flag";
$lang['site_enabled']="Site Enabled";
$lang['save']="Save";
$lang['cancel']="Cancel";
$lang['country_info']="Country Information";
$lang['new_country']="New Country";
$lang['edit_country']="Edit Counry";
$lang['country']="Country";
$lang['home']="Home";
$lang['no']="No";
$lang['action']="Action";
$lang['show']="Show";
?>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with codeigniter?

Comment: How have you loaded the language file have you done it the same as http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include this PHP array in another script, you can use the `include` function.

For example, if you have another file, `index.php` in the same directory, you can `include` it and then you will have access to the variable. You can modify it like a normal variable, like so:

**`index.php`**

```
<?php
    include `lang_array.php`;   // will get the file with the array
    echo $lang["no"];           // should output "No"
    $lang["show"] = "value";    // update $lang["show"]
?>
```

Comment: Not correct way of loading language in codeigniter http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Besides the title and the tag, there is no clear reference to codeigniter. Also, I am not familiar with codeigniter, so this is the best solution I have.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you just have include file using php include function.

```
<?php
include 'file_name.php';
$lang['new_country']="new country 1";
?>
```